# Unknown protocol with Oauth2 on Android

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, android-manifest, deep-linking

I am trying to auth using Oauth2 on android, but my app keeps crashing because it throws the following error :  **Unknown protocol: kiactiv**.

See below :

```
    04-23 02:34:11.440 19202-19202/android.kiactiv I/OAuthAndroid: shouldOverrideUrlLoading: kiactiv://oauth_callback?code=TOKEN
    04-23 02:34:11.441 19202-19202/android.kiactiv I/OAuthAndroid: url: kiactiv://oauth_callback?code=TOKEN, redirect: kiactiv://oauth_callback, callback: true



    04-23 02:34:11.448 19202-19202/android.kiactiv W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: kiactiv
    04-23 02:34:11.448 19202-19202/android.kiactiv W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.parseURL(GenericUrl.java:638)
    04-23 02:34:11.448 19202-19202/android.kiactiv W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:114)
    04-23 02:34:11.448 19202-19202/android.kiactiv W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl.<init>(AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl.java:99)
    04-23 02:34:11.448 19202-19202/android.kiactiv W/System.err:     at com.wuman.android.auth.OAuthDialogFragment$3.interceptUrlCompat(OAuthDialogFragment.java:361)
    04-23 02:34:11.448 19202-19202/android.kiactiv W/System.err:     at com.wuman.android.auth.OAuthDialogFragment$3.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(OAuthDialogFragment.java:316)
    04-23 02:34:11.448 19202-19202/android.kiactiv W/System.err:     at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:336)
```

My gradle file includes these libs :

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services', module: 'google-play-services'
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-java6:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.20.0'
```

and I am excepting the deep link in my manifest file :

```
<activity
            android:name="android.kiactiv.DeepLinkActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "kiactiv://oauth_callback” -->
                <data android:scheme="kiactiv" android:host="oauth_callback" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

My source code is very similar to this [one what I found on github](https://github.com/wuman/android-oauth-client/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/wuman/oauth/samples/foursquare/SimpleOAuth2ImplicitActivity.java) : . I have just replaced the creds and the URLS.

Any clues ?

Cheers

Comment: what is your callback url ?

Comment: @USKMobility my callback is : kiactiv://oauth_callback?code=TOKEN , as written above !

Comment: kiactiv:// is not any protocole, update your url

Comment: @USKMobility but my return URL could be a deeplink ?  I followed the example here : 

http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you find any solution to this >